# Lightbox to be shown as new tab when using mobile device

Tags: asp.net, mobile, lightbox

I am creating a portal which has a responsive design (browser, tablet and mobile compatible). When seen from the browser, there is an icon which opens a lightbox popup.

What I want to achieve is: when viewed from a mobile phone, if I click on this icon, it should load a new tab (instead of the popup). Is this possible?

My server side scripting is in ASP.NET.

Comment: What results could you gain by research? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, Actually I am in the process of finding out a solution. I just wanted to check if this has already been achieved.

Comment: Have you already searched for it here on SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply disable to code to open Lightbox like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) { .zoombox {display: none;} }
```

and open a new tab on click of your button